# $[K:F_1]=[K:F_2]$, are $F_1, F_2$ isomorphic?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

$K$ is a field extension of field $F_1$, $F_2$, **all of them** are finite fields. There is no other conditions. I want to know is the assertion possible?

Could you please give a brief explanation?

Comment: The answer depends of whether $K$ is finite.

Comment: That's a good point: I was assuming below that the $[K:F_i]$ are finite (and thus $K$ is also finite); is that the case?

Answer (score 5):

There's only one finite field of a given order, so yes.

Comment: Not necessarily, if we are allowing infinite extensions.

Comment: Of course. Are we allowing infinite extensions? Certainly if the only requirement is that $[K:F_1], [K:F_2] = \infty$, then $F_1$ and $F_2$ don't have to be isomorphic; take $F_1 = \mathbb{F}_p, F_2 = \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, and $K = \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$.

Comment: And finite extensions in infinite fields?